# Vue merge value in nested object with parent array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

If I have an array where each object has a neste object:

```
    items: [
        {
        id: 1,
        name: Tomato
        category: {
          id: 1,
          name: Vegetable
          }
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        name: Apple
        category: {
          id: 2,
          name: Fruit
        }
        }
  ]
```

How do I get a new array with the field name of the nested object merged in the parent array?

```
 items_extended: [
    {
    id: 1,
    name: Tomato
    category: Vegetable
    },
    {
    id: 2,
    name: Apple
    category: Fruit
    }
]
```

Comment: What are `Tomato` etc? Objects? If they're stings, I recommend putting quotes around them. Can you share a code attempt? Thanks.

Comment: Items is an array of objects. Each item object includes a nestes category object.

Comment: I can see that, but `Apple` is a variable name. What is it?

Comment: name is an attribute of objects in array items. From a db perspective, table items, columns id, name, category_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `map` through the array and return a modified version.

```js
var items_extended = items.map(function (item) {
    return {
        id: item.id,
        name: item.name,
        category: item.category.name,
    };
});
```